# Tor Browser: How to disable NAG “…attempted to extract HTML5 canvas…”

Tags: windows-8.1, privacy, tor, fingerprint, canvas

Constant Nag: "this website (...) attempted to extract HTML5 canvas image data, which may be used to uniquely identify your computer."

There's an option to "remember for this site," which has NEVER remembered anything.  I don't want to be bothered with it even once anyway.

I would like the answer to always be "NO," in advance, so I don't see the NAG.

I have endured this constant annoyance through at least that last four versions of Tor Browser, probably more.

I installed a canvas blocking add-on, hoping it would preempt this, but it failed, so I assume this annoying code is running first.

Currents versions: Windows 8.1, Tor Browser 8.0a6, default plugins (https everywhere, noscript).

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to `about:config`
2. Look for `privacy.resistFingerprinting.autoDeclineNoUserInputCanvasPrompts`
3. Set it to True